# Как составить запрос сортировки с условием в Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, order-by

Есть таблица с колонками в Postgres (text status, timestamptz date1, timestamptz date2)
Нужно составить запрос select с order by по следующему условию.
В начале выводим все со status = 'New' затем сортируем по убыванию date1, если status != 'New' выводим остальные по возрастанию date2.
Как составить подобный запрос?

Comment: *если status != 'New'* Бред какой-то. Во-первых, после первого шага сортировки остались исключительно записи с status != 'New', во-вторых, все они на втором шаге сортированы по убыванию date1 - какой ещё "если"?

Comment: Возможно я неправильно выразился. Вывести нужно всё, и = 'New' и != 'New', но для записей у которых = 'New' сортировка идет по убыванию date1, для записей у которых != 'New' сортируем по возрастанию date2. Но в начале должны стоять записи у которых ='New'.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table order by status = 'New', case status when 'New' then date1 else date2 end;`

Answer (score 3):

Если я правильно понял, то можно сделать два запроса с проверкой на status, отсортировать их по датам, а затем объединить командой UNION ALL

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM table
 WHERE status = 'New' 
 ORDER BY date1 desc
UNION ALL
SELECT *
  FROM table
 WHERE status != 'New' 
 ORDER BY date2
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Судя по всему PostgreSQL не гарантирует порядок сортировки после UNION ALL (Информация взята отсюда https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/28399), хотя в моём случае пример отсортировался корректно

Comment: По ссылке на гитхаб порядок сортировки - скорее вопрос к LINQ. В приведенном ответе, скорее всего ``ORDER BY date2`` будет применено ко всей выборке. ``ORDER BY date1 desc`` - выдаст синтаксическую ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать два подзапроса и объединить через UNION ALL.
В документации PostgreSQL советуют обрамлять подзапросы скобками, для большей однозначности.

```
(SELECT *
  FROM test
 WHERE status = 'New' 
 ORDER BY date1 desc)
UNION ALL
(SELECT *
  FROM test
 WHERE status <> 'New' 
 ORDER BY date2)
```